# Is it possible to have a binary variable display as a checkbox in a datasheet view form?

Tags: ms-access

In MS-Access, if you configure a table to include a binary variable, then that field will display as a checkbox in when you view either the table, or a query based upon that table in datasheet view.

However, if you go one step further an construct a form/subform based upon that query, Access seems to automatically reformat that binary variable so that it displays in the datasheet view of the form as text ("Yes"/"No", "True"/"False", "On"/"Off").

Is it possible to preserve the checkbox presentation of this type of variable in the form datasheet view?

---

EDIT: I should add... I can edit the Lookup->"Display Control" property in the underlying query so that the field I am interested in is set to "Check Box" as it is in the design view of the table.

However, when I go to the design view of my subform, and select Data->"Record Source", the copy of that query that I find there will never retain the "Check Box" property for my binary field. I can change it manually here, but the property is never retained once I save the record source and/or the form.

The lookup display control always reverts back to null, no matter what I do, and the form always displays text instead of a checkbox in datasheet view.

Results are the same, regardless of whether I edit the record source through the main form design view or if I open the subform directly in design view.

Does this sound familiar to anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used Ms Access 2007 for a long time, and whenever a set the fields properties in Table for Yes/No value, automatically, the form would display a checkbox control.

Sometimes, I have to right click in Checkbox to change into EditText, then the value is turned to 0 or -1.

I found it strange because whenever I set to EditText for a field relating to Yes/No value, it showed 0/-1.  Instead, to make an EditText display "Yes/No" literally I had set the properties of the field to "Text" or "ComboBox" (with data source: "Yes" and "No") in Table properties

Comment: (1 of 2) Thank you very much! Your answer has helped me solve my issue. I think it's a good idea to add a few comments on how exactly I was able to connect the dots in my particular case. It actually turned out to be something fairly obvious, but I doubt I ever would have noticed it without your help! .... Basically, I went back in and created an entirely new "dummy" form, based upon the same query as my "live" form mentioned above. Exactly as you said, in the case of the dummy form, the default behavior was to display the binary field as a checkbox. ...

Comment: (2 of 2) I then opened both the live and dummy forms in design view at the same time, and looked for whatever differences I could find between the two. The problem with my live form, as it turns out, was that the actual control for that field had been selected as a text box, instead of a checkbox. I never would have done this had I been building the form from scratch, but in this case I was adapting a previously built form to include the checkbox. ...Simply changing the control type from text box to checkbox, and assigning the corresponding query-field as the data source has solved my problem.

Comment: Again, in retrospect, it seems that this should have been obvious all along, but I would never had noticed that if you had not helped me! Thanks again @tdmsoares!

Comment: @John You're welcome! Glad you solved this issue! In fact most problems I've faced in Ms Acces was adapting, for example, one form into another project than creating from scratch...